# Using 2 D FFT for filtering unwanted texture on an image

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have an image that spurious waves texture appears:

[image: Imag test]

I want to use 2D FFT to remove this texture, so I applied the following code from  [Calculation of 2D FFT for an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87214/calculation-of-2d-fft-for-an-image) :

```
data = ImageData[imag];(*get data*)
{nRow, nCol, nChannel} = Dimensions[data];
d = data[[All, All, 2]];
d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
fw = Fourier[d, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];

(*adjust for better viewing as needed*)
fudgeFactor = 50;
abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw];
Labeled[a = Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 300], Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]]
```

And the result is:

[image: Magnitude Spectrum]

How do I transform the image back using inversefourier? 
So I could eliminate the spurious texture.

I read lot of questions but no one is very clear about how code inverse transform back to "original" image.

Comment: did you see related question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29265/problem-with-fourier-and-inversefourier-function ? you can try data = InverseFourier[fdct]; Image[Chop@data] you need to chop it. the inverse Fourier may have imaginary parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to reverse all the steps you took,

```
ifw = Chop@InverseFourier[fw, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
ifw = ifw*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
idata = Map[{#, #, #} &, ifw, {2}];
GraphicsRow[{Image[idata],
  Image[data]}, ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

I noticed that the three channels of your data aren't **exactly** equivalent, though they are for most of the pixels.  Just evaluate `Length@Select[Flatten[data, 1], UnsameQ @@ # &]` and you'll see that there are 78,825 pixels with some differences.  Of course, their magnitude spectrum looks visually very similar,

[image]

but they aren't numerically identical.  So really, you should split the three channels into different matrices, do a FFT on each, perform the subtraction you are going for, then do the inverse FFT, then combine them.  Fairly straightforward to generalize the code to do that.

**Edit**
This wasn't in your question, but I thought I'd take a crack at removing the unwanted texture (never done anything like this before, so this is bound to be far from the most efficient way to do it).

It's clear from the magnitude spectrum that the problem comes from the zero frequency terms.  Your image has 560 rows and 720 columns.  I don't know if the zero comes at n/2 or n/2+1, so I just check the data,

```
Last@Ordering[Abs@fw[[100]]]
Last@Ordering[Abs@fw[[All, 100]]]
(* 361 *)
(* 281 *)
```

So we can just replace the 361st column with the average of the two columns nearest to it, and do the same for the 281st row.  Perhaps it would be better to just remove these columns and rows, but this is my first attempt.

```
fw2 = fw;
fw2[[All, 361]] = Mean /@ fw2[[All, {360, 362}]];
fw2[[281]] = Mean@fw2[[{280, 282}]];
```

Look a the spectrum without these terms,

```
fudgeFactor = 50;
abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw2];
Labeled[a = Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 300], 
 Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]]
```

[image]

Now take the inverse FFT and compare to the original image,

```
ifw = Chop@InverseFourier[fw2, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
ifw = ifw*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
idata = Map[{#, #, #} &, ifw, {2}];
GraphicsRow[{Image[idata], Image[data]}, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

And here is the code for keeping all three channels,

```
{nRow, nCol, nChannel} = Dimensions[data];
d = data[[All, All, #]] & /@ Range[nChannel];
idata = Module[{d, fw, fw2, ifw},
     d = #*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
     fw = Fourier[#, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
     fw2 = fw;
     fw2[[All, 361]] = Mean /@ fw2[[All, {360, 362}]];
     fw2[[281]] = Mean@fw2[[{280, 282}]];
     ifw = Chop@InverseFourier[fw2, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
     ifw = ifw*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
     ifw
     ] & /@ d;

idata = Transpose[idata, {3, 1, 2}];

Image[idata]
```

[image]

**Edit**
A question was asked about how to tell which column or row to remove, and hopefully this should help in that regard:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvkI1.jpg"];
data = ImageData[img];(*get data*){nRow, nCol, nChannel} = 
 Dimensions[data];
d = data[[All, All, 2]];
d = d*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
fw = Fourier[d, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
Manipulate[
 Module[{fw2, fudgeFactor, abs, ifw, idata, message},
  fw2 = fw;
  If[
   remcol,
   fw2[[All, column]] = Mean /@ fw2[[All, {column - 1, column + 1}]]
   ];
  If[
   remrow,
   fw2[[row]] = Mean@fw2[[{row - 1, row + 1}]]
   ];
  fudgeFactor = 50;
  abs = fudgeFactor*Log[1 + Abs@fw2];
  ifw = InverseFourier[fw2, FourierParameters -> {1, 1}];
  message = "";
  If[Max@Abs@Im@ifw/Max@Abs@Re@ifw > 10^-10, 
   message = 
    "Warning, Inverse FFT returned complex results,\n proceeding with \
real part only"];
  ifw = Re@ifw;
  ifw = ifw*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
  idata = Map[{#, #, #} &, ifw, {2}];
  Row[{
    Labeled[Image[abs/Max[abs], ImageSize -> 500],
     Style["Magnitude spectrum", 18]],
    Labeled[Image[idata, ImageSize -> 500],
     Style["Reconstructed image", 18]],
    message}
   ]
  ],
 {{remcol, False, "Remove Column?"}, {True, False}},
 {{remrow, False, "Remove Row?"}, {True, False}},
 {{row, Floor[nRow/2]}, 2, nRow - 1, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{column, Floor[nCol/2]}, 2, nCol - 1, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: It worked very well, thanks Jason B!

Comment: How do you now the exactly, columns and lines?

Comment: @locometro, see the edit

Comment: Yes , But I didnt get the idea...sorry, i am newbies in FFT image analyses..:)

Comment: @locometro, so when I looked at the spectrum image it was clear there was a large stripe down the middle of both axes (and therefore corresponds to zero frequency).  I assumed this was what you were trying to remove, a general noise term.  To find out exactly which column corresponded to this stripe I used trial and error, doing listplots of the carious rows or columns.

Comment: Then when I took those away I noticed that the image looked like a general noise term had been taken out.  This is literally my first time with image processing as well.   Try the last bit of code I put up, it can help to decide which terms to remove. You can email me at Jason.biggs@mpsd.mpg.de if you like